# Laravel - How to sort external API in desc order and select set of records

Tags: json, laravel

In my Laravel-8, I am getting external API using Guzzle:

I got this set of records for dd($json) in the Controller:

```
array:554 [▼
 0 => array:30 [▼
  "PartitionKey" => "19SB22"
  "RowKey" => "0000"
  "Timestamp" => "2021-01-22T12:30:25.4698261Z"
  "client_tracking_id" => "ddd3321"
  "current_asset_position_name" => "2, Adelaide, Australia"
  "service_tracking_id" => "19SB22"
  "this_tracking_job_id" => "0000"
  "trip_status" => "DISPATCHED"
]
1 => array:31 [▼
  "PartitionKey" => "19SB22"
  "RowKey" => "2233"
  "Timestamp" => "2021-02-23T20:51:50.3066741Z"
  "client_tracking_id" => "TRIP-20200621007"
  "current_asset_position_name" => "20, Adelaide, Australia"
  "service_tracking_id" => "19SB22"
  "this_tracking_job_id" => "19SB22"
  "trip_status" => "AROUND CUSTOMER LOCATION"
]
....
```

Here is the Controller:

```
public function index() {
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET','https://example.com/api/tracking/19SB22', [
       'query' => ['key' => 'jkkmkf']
   ])->getBody();
    $json = json_decode($res->getContents(), true);       
    return view('welcome', [
        'json' => $json,

    ]);
```

How do I sort the result $json in descending order using Timestamp field and select the first set of record?

Thanks

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Collections` and `Carbon` to convert the date string into a correct timestamp.

Collections are laravels array extension, that makes it possible to do function calls on collections (arrays). There is an `sortBy()` and `sortyByDesc()` functions, these can be used and using `Carbon::parse()`, that should be able to parse your zulu date. After that you can use `first()` to get your element.

```
$firstElement = collect($yourData)->sortByDesc(function ($data) {
    return Carbon::parse($data['Timestamp'])->timestamp;
})->first();
```